# MySQL procedure returns empty

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Here is a very basic issue that i have and i assume it might be due to a syntax issues with MySQL sql.

Here is my procedure that i'm having trouble with

```
CREATE DEFINER=`test` PROCEDURE `get_users`(IN user_id INT)
BEGIN
select * from user where user_id = @user_id;
END
```

Calling the procedure as below

```
 call test.get_users(1);
```

I have a user table with user_id values as '1' and i can see results when i use a select statement
    select * from users;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the @ symbol is your problem. this works on my MySQL-DB

```
CREATE DEFINER=`codemagic.net.db`@`%` 
PROCEDURE `get_user`(IN `user_id` INT) 
NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
select * from users where id = user_id
```

regards

- Marcel

Comment: well, removing the '@' fixed it !